# Is it possible to import specific icons from expo vector-icons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am looking to reduce app size and am trying to understand my options. I know I should probably eject and not use Expo, and I plan to eventually do that, but am looking to understand how everything works before I do that.

One of the things I was thinking was importing only certain icons as to avoid importing the entire expo vector icons library in modules where I pull icons. Currently I do the following:

```
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
```

Perhaps this is misguided and if so I'd appreciate the tip, but is it possible/worth importing only certain icons so as to decrease bringing in the entire expo vector icons library? Does it matter?

Lastly I know I could also probably just save those icons I use individually in my assets, but wanted to see if there was an easier solution before going all manual. Thanks.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong but aren't you already importing specific icons by using this import  `import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';` ?

Comment: that is a good point, I guess I thought I could literally import one icon if that was the only icon I used in my module

Answer (score 0):

You could use explicit import method provided by `react-native-fontawesome`.
Here is the sample from doc.
https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-native-fontawesome#explicit-import

```js
// ...
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'
import { faCheckSquare, faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

library.add(fab, faCheckSquare, faCoffee)
```

It may not be an answer to your question since it doesn't use `@expo/vector-icons` but this way you can achieve what you want without ejecting so I thought it could be a good option to consider.
Also, I would like to know if there are other options (like other fonts) to achieve this easily.